# "Not Join" in R

Tags: r, merge, inner-join, data.table, outer-join

I am looking for a quick way to do 'not join' (i.e. keep rows that didn't merge, or inverse of inner join). The way I've been doing is to use data.table for X and Y, then set key. For example:

```
require(data.table)

X <- data.table(category = c('A','B','C','D'), val1 = c(0.2,0.3,0.8,0.7))
Y <- data.table(category = c('B','C','D','E'), val2 = c(2,3,5,7))
XY <- merge(X,Y,by='category')

> XY
   category val1 val2
1:        B  0.3    2
2:        C  0.8    3
3:        D  0.7    5
```

But I need the inverse of this, so I have to do:

```
XY_All <- merge(X,Y,by='category',all=TRUE)
setkey(XY,category)
setkey(XY_All,category)
notXY <- XY_All[!XY]    #data.table not join (finally)

> notXY
   category val1 val2
1:        A  0.2   NA
2:        E   NA    7
```

I feel like this is quite long winded (especially from data.frame). Am I missing something?

EDIT: I got this after thinking more about not joins

```
X <- data.table(category = c('A','B','C','D'), val1 = c(0.2,0.3,0.8,0.7),key = "category")
Y <- data.table(category = c('B','C','D','E'), val2 = c(2,3,5,7), key = "category")
notXY <- merge(X[!Y],Y[!X],all=TRUE)
```

But WheresTheAnyKey's answer below is clearer. One last hurdle is the presetting data.table keys, it'd be nice not to have to do that.

EDIT: To clarify, the accepted solution is:

```
merge(anti_join(X, Y, by = 'category'),anti_join(Y, X, by = 'category'), by = 'category', all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Not in front of an R-console right now, but I believe you should be able to use something similar to ```X[!Y]```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
bind_rows(anti_join(X, Y), anti_join(Y, X))
```

EDIT:
Since someone asked for some explanation, here's what is happening:

The first `anti_join()` function returns rows from `X` that have no matching row in `Y` with the match determined by what the join is joining by.  The second does the reverse.  `bind_rows()` just takes the results of its inputs and makes them into a single `tbl` with all the observations from each of its inputs, replacing missing variable data with `NA`.

Comment: doesn't work this way. to get the expected results with anti_join, you need `merge(anti_join(X, Y, by = 'category'),anti_join(Y, X, by = 'category'), by = 'category', all = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry.  One more step :)

Comment: Instead of just the code, you should also include an explanation of what you're doing and why it answers the question.

Comment: @azurefrog Here's your explanation :)

Comment: That's really nice too. I'm torn

Comment: @tanavach time them to see who wins!

Comment: This solution doesn't 1) require conversion to data.table 2) set the key before merging. So hats off to you! (though WheresTheAnyKey's solution might be more convenient if you use data.table exclusively, since anti_join will convert it to data.frame)

Answer (score 7):

```
setkey(X,category)
setkey(Y,category)

rbind(X[!Y], Y[!X], fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: This condenses the value of A and E to both be labeled "val1", while 0.2=val1 for A and 7=val2 for E

Comment: Good point.  Just changed it.  This solution does not involve a Cartesian join.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it more concise like this:

```
X <- data.table(category = c('A','B','C','D'), val1 = c(0.2,0.3,0.8,0.7),key = "category")
Y <- data.table(category = c('B','C','D','E'), val2 = c(2,3,5,7), key = "category")
notXY <- merge(X,Y,all = TRUE)[!merge(X,Y)]
```

Comment: Almost, I like it! I'd accept this elegant solution if no one else comes up another without presetting key.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @[stanekam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3006597/stanekam)'s answer you can also use `%in%`. This is like [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11556530/rohit)'s usage of `%in%` but using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
bind_rows(X |> filter(!category %in% Y$category),
          Y |> filter(!category %in% X$category))
```

In case you have both columns in one data frame, you can also use a single filter statement. For that we rename the columns first so that they remain in separate variables after combining the data frames:

```
bind_rows(X |> rename(category_X=category), 
          Y |> rename(category_Y=category)) |> 
filter(!category_X %in% category_Y | !category_Y %in% category_X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
First, merge with "all" set to "TRUE". Then take out all complete cases:

```
XY_All <- merge(X,Y,by='category',all=TRUE)
notXY  <- XY_All[!complete.cases(XY_All),]
```

Comment: This will only work if you don't have any `NA` values in any other columns of the tables you are merging.

Comment: I think that is fine, according to what @tanvach is asking for.

Comment: Unfortunately MrFlick is right, the real dataset contains a lot of NAs. But I like how this solution works without setting a key, so have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
require(dplyr)
notXY = merge(X[!X$category %in% Y$category,], Y[!Y$category %in% X$category,],by = 
"category",all = TRUE)
```

One way to look at an Anti-Join is that you need observations from X not in Y and observations from Y not in X concatenated together. This can be achieved in one step as shown above.