# how to select categories that are in one dataset, but not in another in R

Tags: r, dplyr

There are 2 datasets

```
s=structure(list(var1 = c("a", "f", "k", "tt", "ee"), var2 = c("b", 
"g", "l", "qq", "rr"), var3 = c("c", "h", "m", "ff", "cc"), var4 = c("d", 
"i", "n", "gg", "vv"), var5 = c("e", "j", "o", "aa", "xx"), metric_var = c(100L, 
200L, 300L, 567L, 789L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

and

```
medagger=structure(list(var1 = c("a", "z", "w", "f", "k"), var2 = c("b", 
"u", "e", "g", "l"), var3 = c("c", "p", "r", "h", "m"), var4 = c("d", 
"q", "q", "i", "n"), var5 = c("e", "n", "w", "j", "o"), metric_var = c(100L, 
200L, 400L, 500L, 700L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

var1-var5 are categorical variables, their values are categories.
if we do an inner join `s` and a `medagger` we get this result

```
merge(s,medagger,by=c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5"))
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var.x metric_var.y
1    a    b    c    d    e          100          100
2    f    g    h    i    j          200          500
3    k    l    m    n    o          300          700
```

only 3 rows to return, because in these datasets there are the same categories.
However, I need the categories that there are in the `s` dataset but not in the `medagger` dataset
were put in separate dataframes.
In this case, I need the dataframe `new` to appear, which will contain only 2 of these rows from `s` .

```
var1    var2    var3    var4    var5    metric_var
tt  qq  ff  gg  aa  567
ee  rr  cc  vv  xx  789
```

How to do that  the categories that were in `s` but not in the `medagger` appear in the `new` dataframe ?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Not Join" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190444/not-join-in-r)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `anti_join` from `dplyr` library to get the expected result. According to the documentation:

> anti_join() return all rows from x without a match in y.

[documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html)

```
library(dplyr)

df <- s %>%
  anti_join(medagger, by = c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5"))
```

The output will be like this:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var
1   tt   qq   ff   gg   aa        567
2   ee   rr   cc   vv   xx        789
```

Answer (score 3):

The anti-join is the best approach, I think.

### base R

While `dplyr::anti_join` is a convenient one-shot function to do this, if you'd prefer base R, then a two-step of `merge` and `setdiff` works:

```r
merged <- merge(s,medagger,by=c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5"), suffixes = c("",".y"))
setdiff(s, merged[,colnames(s)])
#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var
# 1   tt   qq   ff   gg   aa        567
# 2   ee   rr   cc   vv   xx        789
```

### data.table

The `data.table` `DT1[!DT2]` is its canonical anti-join mechanism, which only requires that keys be set on `DT1`.

```r
library(data.table)
sDT <- as.data.table(s)
medaggerDT <- as.data.table(medagger)
setkeyv(sDT, c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")) # or setkey(S, var1, ...)
sDT[!medaggerDT]
#    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var
# 1:   ee   rr   cc   vv   xx        789
# 2:   tt   qq   ff   gg   aa        567
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
s %>% inner_join(medagger, by=c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")) -> result1

  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var.x metric_var.y
1    a    b    c    d    e          100          100
2    f    g    h    i    j          200          500
3    k    l    m    n    o          300          700
```

and the second dataframe:

```
s %>% anti_join(medagger, by=c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")) -> result2
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var
1   tt   qq   ff   gg   aa        567
2   ee   rr   cc   vv   xx        789
```

In base R, this works assuming that medagger and s do not have NA's:

```
merge(s,medagger,by=c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5"), all.x=T) -> result
result2  <- result[!complete.cases(result),]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `rbind` each row and look if it's not `duplicated`.

```
s[apply(s, 1, \(x) tail(!duplicated(rbind(medagger[1:5], x[1:5])), 1)), ]
#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 metric_var
# 4   tt   qq   ff   gg   aa        567
# 5   ee   rr   cc   vv   xx        789
```